# Managed ("Smart") switch with port status

Tags: networking, switch

I am looking for a managed switch, which can show the current status of the ports (Up/down, speed, duplex if possible). If it's possible < 50 €  and 8 ports would be ideal.

Preferably, but not strictly required, the MAC table associated to that port.

Would be nice if the status could be read easily, if it's a web interface it should do, scraping the status may not be the best, but should do. Telnet/SSH would presumably be better, but I don't know if there are products in that price range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [Mikrotik](http://www.mikrotik.com/) routers based on RouterBoard hardware and RouterOS software. The prices are competitive even with *dumb* switches, reconfiguring the router to act as a switch is perfectly normal (our firm uses them instead of standard switches on regular basis), they are quite robust, and it allows quite in-depth monitoring and control of the network, including per-port basis.

The only serious disadvantage is that the interface is not really intuitive and definitely takes some serious reading of the documentation, even for relatively simple tasks (like aforementioned reconfiguring as a switch). You can easily get lost in the countless features and miss the one you're looking for - the feature-richness may be a bit overwhelming even to a professional.